# Listar Categorias em Árvore no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Estou começando com **Laravel 5.1** e estou um pouco perdido ainda.

Preciso listar categorias, subcategorias e "sub-subcategorias".

### Tabela:

```
Categorias
------------------------
id            | int
nome          | varchar
categoria_pai | int
```

### Dados:

```
id  | nome         | categoria_pai
----------------------------------
1   | Informática  | NULL
2   | Mouse        | 1
3   | Sem fio      | 2
4   | Eletrônicos  | NULL
```

### Model:

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categorias';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'descricao', 'categoria_pai'];

    public function produtos() {
      $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto');
    }

    public function categoriaPai()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }

    public function categoriaFilho()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria');
    }
}
```

### Controller:

Método que monta o select na hora de adicionar outra categoria. Funciona, mas não sei como filtrar isso para fazer optgroup e separar.

```
public function create()
{
    $categorias = Categoria::all()->lists('nome', 'id');
    return view('categorias.adicionar', compact('categorias'));
}
```

Não tenho ideia de como começar, já busquei coisas parecidas mas não encontrei.

Com PHP puro eu já fiz, mas usando o **Laravel**, estou quebrando cabeça.

Comment: Mas o que você precisa ? Fazer o relacionamento no SELECT ou no Model ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza, no model. Coloquei o meu Model na pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> No caso eu preciso listar todas e podem haver infinitos níveis

Então para listar todas as subcategorias de uma categoria independente da quantidade de níveis. Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
mysql> select * from  categoria;
+----+------+--------------+
| id | nome | categoria_id |
+----+------+--------------+
|  1 | cat1 |         NULL |
|  2 | cat2 |            1 |
|  3 | cat3 |            2 |
|  4 | cat4 |            2 |
+----+------+--------------+




class Categoria extends Model{
  ...
   public function subcategorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Categoria::class, 'categoria_id','id');
    }

    public function allSubcategorias()
    {
        return $this->subcategorias()->with('allSubcategorias');
    }
}
```

Busque todas as subcategorias dessa forma:

```
$categoria = Categoria::where('id', 1)->with('allSubcategorias')->first();
return $categoria;
```

Resultado:

```
    
{
    id: 1,
    nome: "cat1",
    categoria_id: null,
    all_subcategorias: [
        {
            id: 2,
            nome: "cat2",
            categoria_id: 1,
            all_subcategorias: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    nome: "cat3",
                    categoria_id: 2,
                    all_subcategorias: [ ]
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    nome: "cat4",
                    categoria_id: 2,
                    all_subcategorias: [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

SQL gerado:

```
    select * from `categoria` where `id` = 1 limit 1;
    select * from `categoria` where `categoria`.`categoria_id` in 1;
    select * from `categoria` where `categoria`.`categoria_id` in 2;
    select * from `categoria` where `categoria`.`categoria_id` in (3, 4);
```

Comment: Show.. Estou sem PC agora, mas já me ajudou a entender. E se eu não quiser setar um id no where('id', 1)? Se eu usar $categoria = Categoria::all()->with('allSubcategorias')->first(); Funciona? Muito obrigado.

Comment: isso: "Categoria::all()->with('allSubcategorias')->first(); " nao funciona.
isso sim: " Categoria::with('allSubcategorias')->get();"

Comment: você pode querer buscar como ponto de partida apenas as categorias raízes.
$categorias = Categoria::whereNull('categoria_id')->with('allSubcategorias')->get();

Answer (score 3):

No relacionamento faltou apenas especificar a coluna do relacionamento:

```
class Categoria {

    public function categoriaPai() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','categoria_pai');
    }

    public function categoriaFilho() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria','categoria_pai');
    }

}
```

E pra capturar de um registro especifico, poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
$categoria = App\Categoria::find(1);
$subcategorias = $categoria->categoriaPai()->get();

foreach ($subcategorias as $sub) {
    $subsubcategorias = $sub->categoriaPai()->get();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Neste caso seria pra eu mostrar uma categoria especifica e suas subcategorias. No caso eu preciso listar todas e podem haver infinitos níveis.

Comment: Alguém conhece outra forma?

Comment: @buback Neste caso crie uma função que faça a recursividade!